# How to evaluate $\cos(\frac{5\pi}{8})$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm  sorry I don't know the way to input pie (3.14) don't have symbol on  my pc

Comment: Pie should be pi (or on fact $\pi$) to make the formulas digestible.

Comment: Do you mean $$\cos\left(5 \times \frac{\pi}{8}\right) ?$$

Comment: It is cos(5π/8). I understand I have to break it up into exact values I know already (i.e. π/4  + π/3) but can't put any that work

Comment: Hint: Use $\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$ with $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{8}$. You know $\cos(5\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac58\pi=\frac12\pi+\frac18\pi$. You know $\sin\frac\pi2$ and $\cos\frac\pi2$, so once you know $\sin\frac\pi8$ and $\cos\frac\pi 8$ you can use the addition formulas. You should also have a formula to compute $\sin \frac\alpha2$ and $\cos\frac\alpha2$ if you know $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$.

Comment: Neither sin(π/8) or cos(π/8) are known exact values.

Comment: They can be made know with the half-angle formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the identity
$$\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2 \theta-1.\tag{1}$$
Let $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{8}$. Then $\cos 2\theta=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. To finish, note that $\cos(5\pi/8)$ is negative.

Comment: i just used the half angle formula, 5π/4 is half of 5π/8 and solved to get -squareroot of 2-root2/4

Comment: There are various ways we can express it. One answer is $-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$. Note the negative sign in front, because $\frac{5\pi}{8}$ is between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$. A simpler-looking expression is $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just work out the details of the previous answer:
$$\cos(\frac{5\pi}{8})=-2^{-\frac{3}{4}}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}=-0.382683...$$

Comment: I did not see Andre's comment when I was typing.  Andre's second expression looks better.